# Adding multiplication to a IF Statement

Tags: c, if-statement, multiplication, statements

I just have one quick  question. How would I introduce multiplication into each of the if statement lines in order to time Height * Width * Depth together to get the volume. Im looking to do this for each line. I have insert a copy of my code and just want to add to it really.

```
{

int Height;
int Width;
int Depth;


scanf("%d%d%d", &Height, &Width, &Depth );

if(Height == Width && Depth >=0){
printf("It's a square cuboid\nThe volume is %d ");

}

if(Height == Depth && Width >= 0)
printf("It's a square cuboid\n ");

if(Width == Depth && Height >= 0)
printf("It's a square cuboid\n");

if(Height == Width && Height == Depth)
printf("It's a perfect cube\n ");


}
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking.  If you want a multiplication, then just write a multiplication ;)

Comment: write `Height * Width * Depth`

Comment: Also I would like the output to be displayed where it said "The volume is %d" but how do I related the %d to the final answer?

Comment: @HadleighGaudreau , I've explained it in my answer

Comment: If it is a perfect cube and all values are >= 0, all the printf statements will get executed.

Answer (score 0):

Declare a fourth variable as `volume`, and then assign value of the multiplication like this

```
int volume;  //declaration of volume

volume=Height * Width * Depth;   //assigning the result of the multiplication to the variable

printf("It's a ['your shape'] \nThe volume is %d ",volume);
```

I hope you may not be going beyond the range of the `int` in case of volume.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit unclear, lets see if i have understood it properly..

You want to check for the volume also in each of the `if` statement conditions..

You can do this like

```
if( (Height * Depth * Width) == YOUR CONDITION )
    printf("WHATEVER YOU WANT\n ");
```

OR, declare another variable and assign the value in that, and then use that in your `if` statement

```
volume = Height * Depth * Width;
if( volume == )
    //whatever you want
```

Answer (score 0):

Though you are going to get some nigativepoints for this but here is how you should write you printif statement. Copy this across to the rest of the if statements if you need to.

```
if(Height == Width && Depth >=0){
printf("It's a square cuboid\nThe volume is %d ", (Height * Width * Depth));

}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear. If you want to multiply,just type `Height*Width*Depth` in the required place. If you want it in a condition in an `if`,use

```
if((Height*Width*Depth)==somevalue)
//Do something
```

However,I think you want to display the volume using below `printf`:

```
printf("It's a square cuboid\nThe volume is %d ");
```

If so,just use

```
printf("It's a square cuboid\nThe volume is %d ",Height*Width*Depth);
```